# Select (ignore if does not exists) for JSON logs Spark SQL

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am new to Apache spark and trying out a few POCs around this. I am trying to read json logs which are structured but a few fields are not always guaranteed, for example : 

 `{
   "item": "A",
   "customerId": 123,
   "hasCustomerId": true,
   .
   .
   .
   },
 {
   "item": "B",
   "hasCustomerId": false,
   .
   .
   .
   }
}`

Assume I want to transform these JSON logs into CSV, I was trying out Spark SQL to get hold of all the fields by simple Select statements but as the second JSON is missing a field(although it does has an identifier) I am not sure how can I handle this.

I want to transform the above json logs to

```
item, customerId, ....

 A  ,   123     , ....

 B  ,   null/0  , ....
```

Comment: You can use sqlContext.read.json(path)

Comment: that will only allow me to read the json, but i am more concerned about reading the missing fields

Answer (score -1):

You should use SqlContext to read the JOSN file, `sqlContext.read.json("file/path")` But if you want to convert it into CSV and then you want to read it with missing values. Your CSV file should be look like

```
item,customerId,hasCustomerId, ....
A,123,, .... // hasCustomerId is null
B,,888, .... // customerId is null
```

i.e. empty record. Then you have to read this like

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
  .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
  .load("file/path")
```